# Jquery calculate difference between values in form radio buttons

Tags: jquery

i have the fallowing question.
Im trying to get this jquery work with my sample sets of radio buttons, to be correct to work with the radio buttons sets which are divided by name value,

here is my code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
        // calc option price differences
        $("label input:radio[name=model]").click(function()
        {
                var _price = $(this).next().val();
                $("label span").remove();
                $("label input:radio[name=model]").map(function()
                {
                        var diff = _price - $(this).next().val();
                        if (diff != 0)
                        {
                                diff = (diff<0) ? '[Add $' + (-diff) + ']' : '[Subtract $' + diff + ']';
                                $(this).parent().append(' <span>' + diff + '</span>');
                        }
                });
        });

        // calc option price differences
        $("label input:radio[name=size]").click(function()
        {
                var _price = $(this).next().val();
                $("label span").remove();
                $("label input:radio[name=size]").map(function()
                {
                        var diff = _price - $(this).next().val();
                        if (diff != 0)
                        {
                                diff = (diff<0) ? '[Add $' + (-diff) + ']' : '[Subtract $' + diff + ']';
                                $(this).parent().append(' <span>' + diff + '</span>');
                        }
                });
        });

        // calc option price differences
        $("label input:radio[name=color]").click(function()
        {
                var _price = $(this).next().val();
                $("label span").remove();
                $("label input:radio[name=color]").map(function()
                {
                        var diff = _price - $(this).next().val();
                        if (diff != 0)
                        {
                                diff = (diff<0) ? '[Add $' + (-diff) + ']' : '[Subtract $' + diff + ']';
                                $(this).parent().append(' <span>' + diff + '</span>');
                        }
                });
        });
});
</script>





<style type="text/css" media="screen">
ul { list-style-type: none; }
span { color: blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="model">
      <li><label for="model1"><input type="radio" id="model1" name="model" value="PART-NO-1" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" value="100.00" /> Model 1</label></li>
      <li><label for="model2"><input type="radio" id="model2" name="model" value="PART-NO-2" /><input type="hidden" value="200.00" /> Model 2</label></li>
      <li><label for="model3"><input type="radio" id="model3" name="model" value="PART-NO-3" /><input type="hidden" value="300.00" /> Model 3</label></li>
</ul>
</form>
<ul id="size">
      <li><label for="size1"><input type="radio" id="size1" name="size" value="PART-NO-4" /><input type="hidden" value="5.00" /> Small</label></li>
      <li><label for="size2"><input type="radio" id="size2" name="size" value="PART-NO-5" /><input type="hidden" value="10.00" /> Medium</label></li>
      <li><label for="size3"><input type="radio" id="size3" name="size" value="PART-NO-6" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" value="15.00" /> Large</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="color">
      <li><label for="color1"><input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" value="PART-NO-7" /><input type="hidden" value="10.00" /> Blue</label></li>
      <li><label for="color2"><input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" value="PART-NO-8" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" value="20.00" /> Red</label></li>
      <li><label for="color3"><input type="radio" id="color3" name="color" value="PART-NO-9" /><input type="hidden" value="30.00" /> Yellow</label></li>
</ul>
```

the thing i want to get to work, is the values be shown after i switch to another radio set, for example if i click on the first radio set which is model it correctly give me subtract or add values but when i click on size radio set the set values from the model radio set disappears, is there any way i could make them stay there regardless what ever set i click next ?

Help or advice would be grateful. Thx in front.

---

i made it somehow worked with span values

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
        // calc option price differences
        $("label input:radio[name=model]").click(function()
        {
                var _price = $(this).next().val();
                $("label span[id='price1']").remove();
                $("label input:radio[name=model]").map(function()
                {
                        var diff = _price - $(this).next().val();
                        if (diff != 0)
                        {
                                diff = (diff<0) ? '[Add $' + (-diff) + ']' : '[Subtract $' + diff + ']';
                                $(this).parent().append(' <span id="price1">' + diff + '</span>');
                        }
                });
        });

        // calc option price differences
        $("label input:radio[name=size]").click(function()
        {
                var _price = $(this).next().val();
                $("label span[id='price2']").remove();
                $("label input:radio[name=size]").map(function()
                {
                        var diff = _price - $(this).next().val();
                        if (diff != 0)
                        {
                                diff = (diff<0) ? '[Add $' + (-diff) + ']' : '[Subtract $' + diff + ']';
                                $(this).parent().append(' <span id="price2">' + diff + '</span>');
                        }
                });
        });

        // calc option price differences
        $("label input:radio[name=color]").click(function()
        {
                var _price = $(this).next().val();
                $("label span[id='price3']").remove();
                $("label input:radio[name=color]").map(function()
                {
                        var diff = _price - $(this).next().val();
                        if (diff != 0)
                        {
                                diff = (diff<0) ? '[Add $' + (-diff) + ']' : '[Subtract $' + diff + ']';
                                $(this).parent().append(' <span id="price3">' + diff + '</span>');
                        }
                });
        });
});
</script>





<style type="text/css" media="screen">
ul { list-style-type: none; }
span { color: blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="model">
      <li><label for="model1"><input type="radio" id="model1" name="model" value="PART-NO-1" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" value="100.00" /> Model 1</label></li>
      <li><label for="model2"><input type="radio" id="model2" name="model" value="PART-NO-2" /><input type="hidden" value="200.00" /> Model 2</label></li>
      <li><label for="model3"><input type="radio" id="model3" name="model" value="PART-NO-3" /><input type="hidden" value="300.00" /> Model 3</label></li>
</ul>
</form>
<ul id="size">
      <li><label for="size1"><input type="radio" id="size1" name="size" value="PART-NO-4" /><input type="hidden" value="5.00" /> Small</label></li>
      <li><label for="size2"><input type="radio" id="size2" name="size" value="PART-NO-5" /><input type="hidden" value="10.00" /> Medium</label></li>
      <li><label for="size3"><input type="radio" id="size3" name="size" value="PART-NO-6" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" value="15.00" /> Large</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="color">
      <li><label for="color1"><input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" value="PART-NO-7" /><input type="hidden" value="10.00" /> Blue</label></li>
      <li><label for="color2"><input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" value="PART-NO-8" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" value="20.00" /> Red</label></li>
      <li><label for="color3"><input type="radio" id="color3" name="color" value="PART-NO-9" /><input type="hidden" value="30.00" /> Yellow</label></li>
</ul>
```

but i have one more question, how to load the values to be shown on checked radio buttons with page load, (i mean values arent shown as the page is loaded, dispite the fact that the values are checked, and then when i click on radio button values are shown. Is there any way to make them show on checked values when page loads ?

Thx in front, also if anyone wanna make the code shorter i would be grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `live` (http://api.jquery.com/live/) function on jQuery and bind it to the radio buttons. Use Javascript to then do whatever changes you want to do.

Comment: i cannot make it work with live, still values disappear when i go to next radio set, another thing is it possible to make them load on page load to show the values on checked radio buttons ?